# Vimrc Method for forcing Vim to open in Command Mode?

Tags: vim

I usually never had to worry about this issue on all vims I've come across previously, however, on a recent setup and configuration of my Windows Subsystem for Linux, I find that the vim which is available always starts in insert mode! I have my own .vimrc I usually plugin in to customize my vim, but never also had to force command mode upon startup, because it is usually the default. So, I've wondered...

How might one force vim to open in command mode -- without having to explicitly press `Esc` upon startup?

Comment: What does `type vim` print? Do you have anything like `au BufRead,BufNewFile * startinsert` in your vimrc?

Comment: @tobifasc `type vim` returns "vim is hashed (/usr/bin/vim)"

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://superuser.com/a/1525060

Comment: @tobifasc that other stuff isn't in my vimrc

Comment: @tobifasc thanks for that link. As it says there, might be a WSL issue, and adding `set t_u7=` to my vimrc solves the problem. However, I still wonder if there's a way to manually force command mode just in case :)

Comment: Fixing the root cause > implementing a workaround.